# inotifywait not listening to DELETE event

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, inotify

I'm using the following bash script to test [inotifywait](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait).

```
while true; do
  inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete "$DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH"
done
```

inotifywait is listening to created files:

```
/directory_to-watch/ CREATE test (copy).sh
```

Also modified files:

```
/directory_to-watch/ MODIFY test.sh
```

But say, I copy a file and then delete it, inotifywait doesn't log anything. What's happening?

Comment: You are restarting `inotifywait` after every event, and with recursion it may have a fairly slow start-up procedure (and be a considerable resource issue). That means there is a race condition against the `rm` command. Try removing the `while true` loop, and using the `--monitor` option in `inotifywait`.

Comment: Does this work `fatrace -t -f 'WD<>+'`?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant that's definitely due an answer

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I removed the while loop and tried this: `inotifywait -r -m -e modify,create,delete "$DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH"` (and without the `-r`). Still, nothing is logged when I delete a file.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why. Pressing Delete was *moving* the file to the trash (I had to listen to this with `moved_from`).

To actually delete the file, I had to press Shift + Delete.